# How to use externally C# classes that create data (from Cypress in JS/TS for instance)?

Tags: c#, database, orm, cypress

We have written our end to end tests in VS19 with C#, Specflow and Selenium. For these tests we already have a lot of C# classes with common methods for creating, updating, deleting data.

These classes make use of Fixtures (these fixtures represent the database schema for a given table).The fixture should allow the user to build an operation with given data, submit to the CoreService, and retrieve a new key for the generated record.

Now we want to start using Cypress for writing some functional tests that will require data setup, data cleanup and updating data as well.
I wonder if there is any way to leverage what we have built on the C#, Specflow side so that we don't redo everything from scratch with Cypress.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the question "how do I reuse my code" is far too broad. How much do you know about the c# ecosystem, or Project References and Nuget References?

Comment: @gunr2171 only a little bit. Currently our test solution has a few projects including mine and I have references to other project so that I can reuse common objects. As for nuget references we have an external CommonUI project that we reference that way to also reuse common methods. 
Would you care to elaborate ?